# Matching text in Dataframe from 2 lists (vectors..)

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I have a data frame with some variables, one of them is text variable:

```
df$text
```

that is free long text.. ( character)

another variable is df$status i use to add "True" or "False" if one of the text elements from listb are found in df$text IF no text element from lista was found:

I'm using 2 vectors of words i search for :

```
lista <-c("apple","fresh orange")
listb <-c("dog","big turtle")
```

how to add df$status <-"True" if there match from one of text elements of listb and df$text ONLY if there is no match between lista and df$text, otherwise assign df$status <-"False"

Comment: It is not exactly clear from your description what you are trying to do. Can you explain perhaps with an example?

Comment: I use: df$status<-str_detect(df$text, paste(listb, collapse="|")) to add "True" to df$status if it there is Match in both listb and df$text , i'm looking to add addtional condition, to make this happen only IF THERE IS NO match between lista and df$text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can check for a condition where `text` matches `listb` but not `lista`.

```
library(stringr)
df$status <- str_detect(df$text, paste(listb, collapse="|")) & 
             !str_detect(df$text, paste(lista, collapse="|"))
```

Or keeping it in base R with `grepl` :

```
df$status <- grepl(paste(listb, collapse="|"), df$text) & 
             !grepl(paste(lista, collapse="|"), df$text)
```